# Sorting a vector of rectangles

Tags: sorting, vector, c++14, sfml

So I'm trying to implement bubble sort algorithm using SFML. I've created a vector in which I'm appending some rectangles and I'll sort them by their heights but it doesn't seem to sort anything. Am I doing something wrong? Please test this code... it's not too much.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    float randomHeight;
    std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> v;
    float currY = 100;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 800), "SFML works!");
    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
       
        randomHeight = rand() % 500 + 200;
        sf::RectangleShape rect({ 4, randomHeight });
        rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
        rect.setRotation(180);
        currY += 10;
        rect.setPosition({ currY, 720 });

        v.push_back(rect);
    }
  

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        
        
        
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            for (auto itj = v.begin(); itj != v.end() - 1; itj = std::next(itj))
            {
                if ((*itj).getSize().y > (*std::next(itj)).getSize().y)
                {
                    std::swap(*itj, *std::next(itj)); 
                }
            }
        }

        for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i = std::next(i))
            window.draw(*i);
        window.display();
       
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping the elements will not change the (x, y) coordinates at which the rectangles are being drawn. So to fix that you will need to swap the coordinates of two rectangles like this

```
std::swap(*itj, *std::next(itj)); 

//Swapping x,y coordinates
int x = (*itj).getPosition().x;
int y = (*itj).getPosition().y;

int x_next = (*std::next(itj)).getPosition().x;
int y_next = (*std::next(itj)).getPosition().y;

(*itj).setPosition( sf::Vector2f(x_next, y_next) );
(*std::next(itj)).setPosition( sf::Vector2f(x, y) );
```

This will sort the rectangles in the increasing order based on their heights.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot the boolean. My c++ is quite rusty so be gentle. Instead of this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    for (auto itj = v.begin(); itj != v.end() - 1; itj = std::next(itj))
    {
        if ((*itj).getSize().y > (*std::next(itj)).getSize().y)
        {
            std::swap(*itj, *std::next(itj)); 
        }
    }
}
```

You should have somthing along these lines:

```
bool swapped = false;
do {
    swapped = false;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        for (auto itj = v.begin(); itj != v.end() - 1; itj = std::next(itj))
        {
            if ((*itj).getSize().y > (*std::next(itj)).getSize().y)
            {
                std::swap(*itj, *std::next(itj)); 
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
} while (swapped);
```

The idea here is that you only end the sorting when you have nothing left to sort. In you original code, you'll compare every rectangle to it's neighbor, then stop. That's not enough: you have to keep at it until every rectangle is close to a sorted rectangle. That's how you know that you're finished.

(I hope I didn't butcher the syntax too much. Think of it as pseudocode if it's better that way.)

Have fun!